# Korean words for "damp"

Tags: word-choice, adjective

In [TOPIKGuide.com's list of 100 most basic Korean adjectives](https://www.topikguide.com/100-most-basic-korean-adjectives-list/), 4 of them are different words for "damp".

- 축축하다: Damp, Clammy, Wet
- 촉촉하다: Moist
- 습하다: Damp, Moist, Humid
- 젖다: Get Wet, Damp

What are the differences in how these words should be used?  When would I choose one of these words over the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 축축하다 adjective

damp weather 축축한(=습한) 날씨

My back is damp with sweat 등에 땀이 축축하다

@습하다 : be a state containing small water. It is commonly used in describing things like weather.

Air is humid so that the bread is wet 공기가 습해서 빵이 축축해 졌다.

> 촉촉한 : Suitable wettish condition

Moist lips is a useful condition when we kiss 키스할때 촉촉한 입술이 좋다

I am in emotionally suitable state 마음이 촉촉해 지다.

The ground need moist when we spread seeds 씨앗을 심을때 촉촉한 흙이 좋다.

> 젖다 : soak : A reason why it is wet.

My shirt is wet so that I must choose another one (I am sexy)
 내 옷이 땀에 젖었다. 그래서 갈아 입어야 한다 (섹시하다)

I am a slave of drink 나는 술에 젖어 산다